# Designing a Logic Circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Design a circuit that will light the same number of LEDs as there are active switches. You will utilize three switches as input. The LEDs should be lit as a bar-magnitude display.

The output pattern should look as follows:

```
Active Input switch count    LED bar-magnitude display (vertical)
no switches active            0 - 0 - 0
any 1 switch active           1 - 0 - 0
any 2 switches active         1 - 1 - 0
all 3 switches active         1 - 1 – 1.
```

[schematic http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/attachments/upload_2015-2-1_17-51-59-png.79759/](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/attachments/upload_2015-2-1_17-51-59-png.79759/)

Comment: Since this is obviously a homework question, here's a hint: The LEDs for "any 1 switch" and "all 3 switches" are easy -- an OR gate and an AND gate, respectively. So, how would you go about implementing the logic for "any 2 switches" to light the middle LED?

Comment: I have tried designing the circuit but its not working...

Comment: If you show us what you tried, we can discuss it.

Comment: I have three switches and three LEDs and when any switch is active then one LED should light up. I am trying to attach the circuit I have tried but I cant or i dont know how to attach it here..

Comment: Assuming you already have it as an image, edit your question and hit control-G to insert it. You will have the option of browsing to your picture to upload it. If you do not already have an image, you can edit your question and then hit control-M to bring up the built-in schematic editor.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea; the only problem is how you've wired up your switches. Instead of connecting them directly between Vcc and Gnd, you need to add a pullup resistor to each one, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhQlld.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>